# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS fails to detect external SSD connected via USB

Tags: 20.04, usb, ssd, usb-drive, drive

I was recently given a used external SSD and I want to connect it to my laptop, which is running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. When I connect the SSD via USB, Ubuntu does not seem to detect it. I do not know how the SSD was previously formatted or with which OS it was used.

No sign of the drive in Files (the file manager) or Disks (the partitioning tool). No sign of the drive in `lsblk` output.

It appears to be represented by this line in the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 052: ID 0525:338a Netchip Technology, Inc. Envoy
```

And here's the output of `dmesg` after connecting the SSD:

```
[2496004.220878] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 98 using xhci_hcd
[2496004.245090] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496004.245100] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496004.245104] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496004.245106] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496004.245109] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496009.404840] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2496009.404911] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496009.405038] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496009.405720] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496009.584720] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 98
[2496009.877000] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 99 using xhci_hcd
[2496009.899707] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496009.899718] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496009.899722] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496009.899724] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496009.899726] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496015.036748] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496015.036888] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496015.037566] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496015.216744] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 99
[2496015.516939] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 100 using xhci_hcd
[2496015.540107] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496015.540118] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496015.540122] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496015.540124] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496015.540126] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496020.668912] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2496020.668985] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496020.669120] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496020.669755] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496020.848774] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 100
[2496021.136910] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 101 using xhci_hcd
[2496021.159825] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496021.159835] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496021.159839] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496021.159841] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496021.159844] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496026.300892] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2496026.300963] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496026.301097] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496026.301810] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496026.480804] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 101
[2496026.769045] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 102 using xhci_hcd
[2496026.792301] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496026.792311] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496026.792315] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496026.792317] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496026.792319] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496031.932980] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2496031.933080] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496031.933215] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496031.933888] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496032.112714] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 102
[2496032.413075] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 103 using xhci_hcd
[2496032.436153] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496032.436164] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496032.436167] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496032.436170] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496032.436172] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496037.564908] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2496037.564999] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496037.565127] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496037.565825] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496037.744849] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 103
[2496038.017052] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 104 using xhci_hcd
[2496038.044343] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496038.044353] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496038.044357] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496038.044359] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496038.044362] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496043.196930] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496043.197068] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496043.197823] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496043.376854] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 104
[2496043.649113] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 105 using xhci_hcd
[2496043.672232] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496043.672243] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496043.672246] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496043.672249] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496043.672251] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496048.829050] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496048.829615] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496048.830359] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496049.008854] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 105
[2496049.309020] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 106 using xhci_hcd
[2496049.332402] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496049.332412] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496049.332416] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496049.332418] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496049.332420] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496054.461015] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496054.461155] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496054.461829] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496054.640880] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 106
[2496054.913129] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 107 using xhci_hcd
[2496054.935943] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496054.935954] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496054.935957] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496054.935960] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496054.935962] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496060.092991] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496060.093132] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496060.093790] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496060.272883] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 107
[2496060.577147] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 108 using xhci_hcd
[2496060.599962] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496060.599972] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496060.599976] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496060.599978] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496060.599980] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496065.725072] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2496065.725233] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496065.725562] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496065.726496] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496065.908918] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 108
[2496066.209182] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 109 using xhci_hcd
[2496066.232345] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496066.232355] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496066.232359] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496066.232361] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496066.232364] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496071.357121] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496071.357331] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496071.358018] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496071.536895] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 109
[2496071.813201] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 110 using xhci_hcd
[2496071.836458] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496071.836469] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496071.836472] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496071.836475] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496071.836477] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496076.988927] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496076.989048] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496076.989609] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496077.168829] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 110
[2496077.473004] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 111 using xhci_hcd
[2496077.495237] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496077.495244] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496077.495247] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496077.495249] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496077.495251] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496082.620941] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496082.621073] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496082.621354] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496082.800966] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 111
[2496083.085235] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 112 using xhci_hcd
[2496083.108708] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496083.108719] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496083.108722] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496083.108724] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496083.108727] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496088.253187] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496088.253311] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496088.254058] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496088.436841] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 112
[2496088.721022] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 113 using xhci_hcd
[2496088.743793] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496088.743802] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496088.743806] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496088.743808] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496088.743810] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496093.885133] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496093.885329] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496093.886019] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496094.065016] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 113
[2496094.353261] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 114 using xhci_hcd
[2496094.380039] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496094.380050] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496094.380053] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496094.380056] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496094.380058] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496099.516998] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2496099.517050] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496099.517130] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496099.517294] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496100.120885] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 114
[2496100.669089] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 115 using xhci_hcd
[2496100.691296] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496100.691306] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496100.691310] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496100.691312] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496100.691314] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496105.917131] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496105.917331] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496105.917926] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496106.097049] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 115
[2496106.409269] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 116 using xhci_hcd
[2496106.432592] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496106.432602] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496106.432606] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496106.432608] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496106.432611] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496111.549167] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2496111.549228] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496111.549322] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496111.549736] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496111.729019] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 116
[2496112.029210] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 117 using xhci_hcd
[2496112.055865] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496112.055877] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496112.055880] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496112.055883] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496112.055885] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496117.181265] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496117.181390] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496117.181944] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496117.372943] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 117
[2496117.661334] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 118 using xhci_hcd
[2496117.684070] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496117.684080] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496117.684084] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496117.684086] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496117.684088] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496122.813301] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496122.813444] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496122.814030] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496122.997006] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 118
[2496123.289207] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 119 using xhci_hcd
[2496123.311687] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496123.311696] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496123.311700] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496123.311702] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496123.311704] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496128.445265] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496128.445417] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496128.446692] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496128.625115] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 119
[2496128.921370] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 120 using xhci_hcd
[2496128.944666] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496128.944677] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496128.944680] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496128.944683] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496128.944685] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496134.077241] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496134.077379] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496134.078121] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496134.257116] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 120
[2496134.561339] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 121 using xhci_hcd
[2496134.584593] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496134.584604] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496134.584607] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496134.584610] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496134.584612] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496139.709261] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496139.709401] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496139.710220] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496139.889015] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 121
[2496140.177343] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 122 using xhci_hcd
[2496140.200793] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496140.200804] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496140.200807] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496140.200810] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496140.200812] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496140.204454] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496140.204844] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496141.397156] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 122
[2496151.545246] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 123 using xhci_hcd
[2496151.567479] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496151.567488] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496151.567491] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496151.567493] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496151.567495] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496156.605384] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2496156.605472] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496156.605613] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496156.605955] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496156.785165] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 123
[2496157.085471] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 124 using xhci_hcd
[2496157.112723] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496157.112733] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496157.112736] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496157.112739] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496157.112741] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496162.202705] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496162.202842] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496162.203661] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496162.378377] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 124
[2496162.666038] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 125 using xhci_hcd
[2496162.686808] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496162.686819] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496162.686823] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496162.686825] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496162.686828] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496167.680595] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2496167.680666] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496167.680807] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496167.681523] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496167.856947] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 125
[2496168.143990] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 126 using xhci_hcd
[2496168.166152] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496168.166162] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496168.166166] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496168.166168] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496168.166170] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496173.237756] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496173.237895] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496173.238585] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496173.420060] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 126
[2496173.705770] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 127 using xhci_hcd
[2496173.732178] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496173.732187] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496173.732190] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496173.732193] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496173.732195] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496178.832846] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496178.832982] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496178.833726] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496179.011812] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 127
[2496179.286972] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[2496179.310087] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496179.310098] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496179.310101] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496179.310104] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496179.310106] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496184.446014] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496184.446232] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496184.446959] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496184.629290] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[2496184.916857] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[2496185.045706] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496185.045715] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496185.045718] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496185.045721] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496185.045723] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496190.067517] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2496190.067588] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496190.067714] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496190.068341] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496190.247082] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[2496190.550874] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[2496190.573833] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496190.573843] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496190.573846] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496190.573848] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496190.573850] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496195.694507] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496195.694638] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496195.695392] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496195.874385] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[2496196.146711] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[2496196.170085] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496196.170096] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496196.170099] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496196.170102] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496196.170104] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496201.325801] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2496201.325869] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496201.325988] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496201.326652] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496201.505714] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[2496201.781926] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[2496201.805192] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496201.805201] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496201.805205] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496201.805207] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496201.805209] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496206.956643] usb 4-1: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2496206.956728] usb 4-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[2496206.956857] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496206.957437] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496207.140286] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[2496207.444493] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[2496207.466692] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496207.466702] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496207.466705] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496207.466707] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496207.466709] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496207.469688] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496207.470216] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[2496208.493130] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     OWC      Envoy            1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 3
[2496208.493624] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[2496208.494202] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 1954210120 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[2496208.675965] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[2496208.691972] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[2496208.691980] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[2496208.691996] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[2496208.692002] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[2496208.692449] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[2496208.692452] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[2496208.692456] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[2496208.692462] sda: detected capacity change from 1954210120 to 0
[2496208.692467] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[2496209.064154] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[2496209.091204] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0525, idProduct=338a, bcdDevice= 0.01
[2496209.091215] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2496209.091218] usb 4-1: Product: Envoy  
[2496209.091220] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: OWC
[2496209.091223] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[2496209.095357] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2496209.096049] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
```

What should be my next steps for diagnosing/solving this issue? Is it worth upgrading Ubuntu?

Comment: I doubt an Ubuntu upgrade would help.  Check for any firmware upgrades for the device from the vendor.  If it eventually becomes visible as sda, try gparted or some other partitioning tool, add a GPT partition table, and add a partition of type Linux filesystem (83).  Then sudo mkfs -text4 /dev/sda1

Comment: A version upgrade is not a tool for fixing a problem and can make it much worse.